# How can mypy ignore a single line in a source file?

Tags: python, types, mypy

I'm using [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) in my python project for type checking. I'm also using PyYAML for reading and writing the project configuration files. Unfortunately, when using the [recommended import mechanism from the PyYAML documentation](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) this generates a spurious error in a try/except clause that attempts to import native libraries:

```
from yaml import load, dump
try:
    from yaml import CLoader as Loader, CDumper as Dumper
except ImportError:
    from yaml import Loader, Dumper
```

On my system `CLoader` and `CDumper` aren't present, which results in the errors `error: Module 'yaml' has no attribute 'CLoader'` and `error: Module 'yaml' has no attribute 'CDumper'`.

Is there a way to have mypy ignore errors on this line? I was hoping that I could do something like this to have mypy skip that line:

```
from yaml import load, dump
try:
    from yaml import CLoader as Loader, CDumper as Dumper  # nomypy
except ImportError:
    from yaml import Loader, Dumper
```

Answer (score 346, accepted):

You can ignore type errors with `# type: ignore` as of [version 0.2](https://github.com/python/mypy/commit/c0334e419a8b50eb4844e5dadc48399036f12ed3) (see issue [#500, Ignore specific lines](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/500)):

> [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) uses `# type: ignore` for **ignoring type errors on particular lines** ...
>
> Also, using `# type: ignore` close to the top of a file **[skips] checking that file altogether**.
>
> <sub>Source: [mypy#500](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/500#issuecomment-86340780). See also the [mypy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#spurious-errors-and-locally-silencing-the-checker).</sub>

Comment: Any idea how to put the # type: ignore on the line above?

Comment: my prospector linter requires a certain length

Comment: @GregHilston ah, ouch. Unfortunately I don't know if this is possible [(PEP 484 doesn't seem to list many other options)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#compatibility-with-other-uses-of-function-annotations), though it is possible to ignore an entire function ([mypy#557](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/557)).

Comment: @GregHilston you could split the line using `\\` or parenthesis and write the comment to the line where the mypy error occurs.

Comment: To be more specific, MyPy supports specifying the error code/s to ignore with `type: ignore[code, ...]`. See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_codes.html?#silencing-errors-based-on-error-codes. In this case, it would be `# type: ignore[attr-defined]`.

Comment: thanks @GinoMempin and for other cases, you can run mypy with the `--show-error-codes` flag to see the codes

Answer (score 42):

Also `# mypy: ignore-errors` at the top of the file works if you want to ignore **all** errors in the **whole** file. If you are using shebang and coding lines, they should be ordered like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# mypy: ignore-errors
```

Source: [Gvanrossum comment to a related mypy issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/626#issuecomment-513872398)

Comment: Note this ignore **all** errors on the **whole** file, not just errors on a single line like what OP was asking about.

Comment: That's why I write "all", sure it is not the accepted answer like the OP wanted, but just an complement to this thread. If you want to add to the answer write an edit or another answer :)

Answer (score 16):

Note that `# type: ignore` will ignore *all* errors. If you don't want that, ignore only the specific error code.

Example:

```
def knows(a: int, b: int) -> bool:  # type: ignore[empty-body]
    pass
```

The above ignores error code `empty-body` for function `knows`. If you want to ignore a specific error for the whole file, put the following on top of the file, just after the imports:

```
# mypy: disable-error-code="empty-body"
```

Answer (score 13):

Of course, the answer of this question is add `# type:ignore` at the end of the line that want mypy to ignore it.

When I was google for how to ignore the files for django migrations,
this question was recomment to me several times.

So I post an answer about how to ignore Django migrations:

```
# mypy.ini
[mypy-*.migrations.*]
ignore_errors = True
```

And for mypy>=0.910, pyproject.toml is supported which can be set as follows:

```
[tool.mypy]
python_version = 3.8
ignore_missing_imports = true

[[tool.mypy.overrides]]
module = "*.migrations.*"
ignore_errors = true
```

Comment: Note that this will ignore errors *for the entire file* and *for all types of errors*, not just for  the error on a *specific line* (which the OP was originally asking about).

Answer (score 8):

I used

```
# type: ignore # noqa: F401
```

to ignore one line that was giving me F401 error. I am sure you can expand it to other error codes

Comment: You mean ignore mypy and Pyflakes errors?

Comment: It seems like you're ignoring mypy and flake8 errors. Also, `type: ignore` is going to ignore _all rules_, not just one, which is not as specific as ignoring F401 only.