# Is there a way to ignore mypy checks on a single function?

Tags: python, mypy, typechecking

You can ignore mypy checks on a individual lines as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220022/how-can-mypy-ignore-a-single-line-in-a-source-file). Is there a way to ignore mypy for a full function?

Comment: What exactly do you want mypy to ignore? Is the function annotated, but mypy should not use these annotations? Should the *usage* or the *implementation* be ignored, or both? Should the function be checked, but the result ignored?

Comment: Good clarifying question. I found this answer while looking for a solution to the former (I want mypy to be quiet about usage of a particular imported function).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

mypy checks can be ignored for a full function by adding `@typing.no_type_check` decorator on top of the function.

```
import typing
@typing.no_type_check
def some_function():
    ...
```

Comment: This doesn't just turn off type checking, but additionally removes any annotations from the function's definition.

Comment: `@typing.no_type_check` might be a very big hammer, but it served wonderfully for sidestepping a bug in _mypy_ that caused it to crash on a certain function.

Comment: Strangely this doesn't work in some cases, adding it did silence some errors but not others (eg: `class Foo(bar_module_PrivateClass)` defined inside a function)