# kwarg unpacking with mypy

Tags: python, mypy, keyword-argument

I have a function, that accepts inputs of different types, and they all have default values. For example,

```
def my_func(a: str = 'Hello', b: bool = False, c: int = 1):
    return a, b, c
```

What I want to do is define the non-default kwargs in a dictionary, and then pass this to the function. For example,

```
input_kwargs = {'b': True}
result = my_func(**input_kwargs)
```

This works fine in that it gives me the output I want. However, mypy complains giving me an error like:

```
error: Argument 1 to "my_func" has incompatible type "**Dict[str, bool]"; expected "str".
```

Is there any way to get around this. I don't want to manually enter the keywords each time, as these input_kwargs would be used multiple times across different functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a class (by inheriting [from `TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict)) with class variables that match with `my_func` parameters. To make all these class variables as [optional, you can set `total=False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict).

Then use this  class as the type for `input_kwargs` to make mypy happy :)

```
from typing import TypedDict

class Params(TypedDict, total=False):
    a: str
    b: bool
    c: int

def my_func(a: str = 'Hello', b: bool = False, c: int = 1):
    return a, b, c

input_kwargs: Params = {'b': True}
result = my_func(**input_kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, but it turns out it is only required if there are missing parameters.
By using the suggested `TypedDict`, the more specific
```
Missing positional arguments "a", "b", "c"
```
is shown, which helps tracking it down

Comment: Mypy sometimes doesn't understand the pythonic way. I simply prefer a `# type: ignore`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220022/how-can-mypy-ignore-a-single-line-in-a-source-file .