# Is there a way to ignore "Mypy: Call to untyped function "setupUi" in typed context [no-untyped-call]" for the UI call when using PySide6

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, mypy, pyside6

I create my `.ui` files with QT Designer and convert them to a python file using the `pyside6-uic ...` command. Each time I load such an `auto-generated' python file via :

```py
class MyCrazyTestDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self) -> None:

        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MyCrazyTestDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

the line `self.ui.setupUi(self)` will generate the mypy error:

```
Mypy: Call to untyped function "setupUi" in typed context [no-untyped-call]
```

I have tried several ways to exclude all auto-generated files from the mypy search. But had no success. The obvious solution with `self.ui.setupUi(self) # type: ignore` does not work either, because it will complain about calling an untyped function in the type environment for every line that uses `self.ui`...

I have already installed the unofficial pyside6 stubs from [here](https://github.com/python-qt-tools/PySide6-stubs), which helped with mypy errors for the self.translate qt code, but it does not help here.

Does anyone know how I can configure my mypy setup so that it will ignore calls to the auto-generated files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can mypy ignore a single line in a source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220022/how-can-mypy-ignore-a-single-line-in-a-source-file)

Comment: You need to add "# type: ignore" to only three lines, one for calling the ```Ui_MyCrazyTestDialog()```, one for calling the ```setupUi()```, and one for calling the ```retranslateUi()```.

Comment: What about disabling [disallow-untyped-calls](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_code_list2.html#check-that-no-untyped-functions-are-called-no-untyped-call) option?