# Python static typing: How to tell the static type checker that my function has checked the type?

Tags: python, static-analysis

I have the following code:

```
ExprType: TypeAlias = int | str | datetime

def check_type(value: ExprType, expected_type: type[ExprType]):
    if not isinstance(value, expected_type):
        raise TypeError(f"Expected {expected_type}, but got {type(result)}.")

value: ExprType = 0

# ... more processing ...

if m := re.match("(\d+)", text_var):
    check_type(value, int)
    value += int(m.group(1))
```

Now, in the last line I'm positively sure that the old value of `value` is an integer, because it was checked by the `check_type` function. However, VSCode (Pylance) is not so sure about it and warns me that:

```
Operator + is not supported for types ExprType and int.
```

To provide an analogy:

```
my_var: int | None = 5       # type(my_var) = int | None

if my_var:                   # type(my_var) = int | None
    print("I'm not None")    # type(my_var) = int
else:
    print("I'm None")        # type(my_var) = NoneType
```

In this case, Pylance uderstands that the type of `my_var` is `int | None` on the `if` line, but it changes its type *inside* the `if` command. What I want to do is to instruct Pylance that my function `check_type` works as a type checker, too.

Comment: There are so many basic errors in this, undefined variables, extra close parens, invalid string literal, etc. etc. Please clean this up into something we can copy/paste into an IDE.

Comment: `check_type` performs a runtime type check. It cannot feed its information into a *static* type checker.

Comment: @matszwecja not necessarily, if the type checker is capable of CFA it is possible for it to narrow the type statically based on the check. Pyright seems able to do so, mypy does not.

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0647/

Comment: @shadowtalker - This is what I was looking for - unfortunately, matszwecja was quicker to give a full answer. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@shadowtalker's suggestion with TypeGuards is a really good approach, but you need to add a TypeVar separate from TypeAlias, to let typechecker know that your function checks for type passed as 2nd argument:

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import TypeAlias, TypeGuard, TypeVar
import re

ExprType: TypeAlias = int | str | datetime
T = TypeVar("T", int, str, datetime)

def check_type(value: ExprType, expected_type: type[T]) -> TypeGuard[T]:
    if not isinstance(value, expected_type):
        raise TypeError(f"Expected {expected_type}, but got {type(value)}.")
    else:
        return True

value: ExprType = 0

# ... more processing ...
text_var = "asdf"
if m := re.match(r"(\d+)", text_var):
    if check_type(value, int):  # type guards require conditional clauses, you cannot rely on exceptions.
        value += int(m.group(1))
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Various type checkers have different ways of disabling checking. A typical way is to add `# type: ignore` at the end of a line (e.g., see previous SO answer at [How can mypy ignore a single line in a source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220022/how-can-mypy-ignore-a-single-line-in-a-source-file)).

Another option which may work is to put a line like `assert instance(value, int)` right before the line which your type checker complains about. In my experience type checkers don't always go deep into a function call to figure out what will happen outside the function call but the assertions can help give the type checker a useful hint.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was too quick to ask and too slow to experiment.

Both:

```
if type(value) is int:
    value += int(m.group(1))
else:
    raise TypeError(...)
```

and

```
if isinstance(value, int):
    value += int(m.group(1))
else:
    raise TypeError(...)
```

work as expected. I was hoping for a more concise solution where the raise command would be hidden in a function call, but a quick reorganization of the code can mitigate it.