# Is there a shorter way to tell Mypy that a given optional chaining is fine?

Tags: python, mypy, optional-chaining

I am working on Python code where the domain logic makes it natural to have a class with an optional field of a second class, which itself has an optional field of a third class. Boiling it down to a minimum working example, this is what I mean:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, number: int) -> None:
        self.number = number

class B:
    def __init__(self, c: C | None) -> None:
        self.c = c

class A:
    def __init__(self, b: B | None) -> None:
        self.b = b
```

At some point in our code, we are receiving an object `a` of class `A` where we know that the field `a.b` is not `None` and furthermore that that the nested field `a.b.c` is not `None`. Of course, mypy does not know this and sensibly informs us that we might be doing something stupid:

```
# Here is an object where it is guaranteed that we won't encounter None values
a = A( B( C(1337) ) )

print(a.b.c.number)   # mypy sensibly returns two errors:
                      # Item "None" of "B | None" has no attribute "c"
                      # Item "None" of "C | Any | None" has no attribute "number"

# This satisfies mypy:
assert (a.b is not None) and (a.b.c is not None)
print(a.b.c.number)
```

This `assert` statement works perfectly well, but it looks cumbersome when our fields names are longer and the nesting goes deeper. Is there a neater and shorter way to satisfy mypy?

Comment: not direct answer but you can always tell pypy to GTFO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220022/how-can-mypy-ignore-a-single-line-in-a-source-file

Comment: Maybe if you provided a more realistic example of how you use these classes, someone could suggest ways to refactor your code in a way which avoids this situation. As it is, it is actually an XY problem.

Comment: Probably better to think about why `A` and `B` accept `None` in the first place, and see if that's necessary.

Comment: Aside: I think `Optional[C]` is preferable to `C | None`

Comment: @Barmar nope, `Optional` vs union-None is purely stylistic preference, there's no strong consensus. I prefer the latter, since it's one import and 3-5 keystrokes less (and `Optional` has never been a good name, I'd reconsider my opinion were it called `Noneable`), and also it looks nicer where C is already a union (`X | Y | None` vs `Optional[X | Y]`) IMO. Here's a relevant discussion: https://discuss.python.org/t/clarification-for-pep-604-is-foo-int-none-to-replace-all-use-of-foo-optional-int/26945/39